# "Несмотря на то(,) что"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

"В связи с этим, несмотря на то_ что Трудовой кодекс допускает оформлять отпуск запиской, более предпочтительным является издание приказа".
Разбивается ли здесь "несмотря на то что" запятой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Несмотря на то что - составной подчинительный союз. Запятая не нужна. Предложение из 2 частей. Внутри главной части находится придаточная. Две запятых: одна открывает придаточное, другая закрывает. Больше не нужно...